# How can I synchronize the animation of multiple SKSpriteNodes?

Tags: ios, animation, swift, sprite-kit

I have several different SKSpriteNodes that are animated. New nodes spawn at unpredictable times during gameplay, but I would like them to spawn with the their animation synchronized with the existing nodes.

Currently, I start the animation from the beginning in the init() by running an action:

```
func init() {
  let textures = GlobalVariableTexturesArray
  let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(...)
  let repeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)
  runAction(repeat)
}
```

The only way I can think to accomplish synchronization is to do my own math and figure out the current frame during the GameScene.update(). Then apply this texture to all of my nodes directly.

Comment: indeed, you would have to animate texture changes manually rather than using actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the update method for the scene you will need to manually set the texture for each sprite in question.

This might be close. It assumes all of the nodes are directly on some kind of background layer, and all of your nodes conform to a subclass you have defined which implements a method called setNextFrame:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    [self.bgLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"nodesNameToAnimate" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [(MySubClassedNode*)node setNextFrame:currentTime];
    }];
}
```

Comment: This is roughly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a parent-node and run the action on this node. Then you can new nodes and they will move synchron:

```
var parentNode = SKNode()

parentNode.addChild(child1)
parentNode.addChild(child2)

parentNode.runAction(yourAction)
```

Comment: moving together, yes, but the question was about frame/texture animations